# Node/Express app not responding to post method

Tags: node.js, express, angular8

I have a Node/Express backend listening to Angular8 front-end. But when I tried to send data to a POST method from the angular client, I got no response from the server. The function doesn't show that it has been reached, and doesn't print any message to the console.
the function in angular8 service is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Recommend } from '../classes/recommend';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecommendsService {

  url:string = "http://localhost:3000/recommend/";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  saveRecommend(rec:any)  { 
  return  this.http.post<Recommend>(this.url + "saveRecommend", rec);
  }
}
```

The Node/Express POST method is:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var recommendDomain = require('../domain/recommend');

router.post('/saveRecommend', async function(req, res){
    console.log("I am here")
    var response = await recommendDomain.addRecommend(req.body);
    res.send(response);
})

module.exports = router;
```

The app.js page where I configured the router is:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static('public'))


console.log("server 1")

var recommendAction = require('./action/recommend')

app.use('/recommend', recommendAction);

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Api Project Works'))
module.exports = app
```

Other similiar POST and GET mehods in my app do work correctly. But the most annoying part is, that running the app in the browser doesn't show any error in the console. Even not '404 not found'.
Can anyone have any idea of what the problem might be?

Comment: Check the `Network` tab in the Dev Tools in your browser. Maybe there will be some info

Comment: do you subscribe to the `this.http.post...` (Happened more than once to me that i didn't ;) )

Comment: Thanks! subscription really solved the problem, so I'll know from now on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, you need to subscribe to the Observable returned from
`this.http.post...`

so at least you have to do this.

`saveRecommend('rec').subscribe();`

Answer (score 0):

You should determine the type of value to return.
try to write
`saveRecommend(rec:any):Observable<Recommend>  {}`
In ***type***-script it's quite important to determine the ***type*** of your functions/variables